# How can I clone a DateTime object in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime, clone

How can I clone a DateTime object in C#?

Comment: Why would you even need to clone a `DateTime`, it's immutable.

Answer (score 230, accepted):

**DateTime is a value type** (`struct`)

This means that the following creates a copy:

```
DateTime toBeClonedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime cloned = toBeClonedDateTime;
```

You can also safely do things like:

```
var dateReference = new DateTime(2018, 7, 29);
for (var h = 0; h < 24; h++) {
  for (var m = 0; m < 60; m++) {
    var myDateTime = dateReference.AddHours(h).AddMinutes(m);
    Console.WriteLine("Now at " + myDateTime.ToShortDateString() + " " + myDateTime.ToShortTimeString());
  }
}
```

Note how in the last example `myDateTime` gets declared anew in each cycle; if `dateReference` had been affected by `AddHours()` or `AddMinutes()`, `myDateTime` would've wandered off really fast – but it doesn't, because `dateReference` stays put:

```
Now at 2018-07-29 0:00
Now at 2018-07-29 0:01
Now at 2018-07-29 0:02
Now at 2018-07-29 0:03
Now at 2018-07-29 0:04
Now at 2018-07-29 0:05
Now at 2018-07-29 0:06
Now at 2018-07-29 0:07
Now at 2018-07-29 0:08
Now at 2018-07-29 0:09
...
Now at 2018-07-29 23:55
Now at 2018-07-29 23:56
Now at 2018-07-29 23:57
Now at 2018-07-29 23:58
Now at 2018-07-29 23:59
```

Answer (score 30):

```
var original = new DateTime(2010, 11, 24);
var clone = original;
```

`DateTime` is a value type, so when you assign it you also clone it. That said, there's no point in cloning it because it's immutable; typically you'd only clone something if you had the intention of changing one of the copies.

Comment: +1 Agreed. The way I got around the problem was to create a new DateTime object and just copy the required parts I wanted to clone such as (day, month, year) from the original datetime object and then set the time manually for the new object.... as an example.

Answer (score 15):

DateTime is a value type so everytime you assign it to a new variable you are cloning.

```
DateTime foo = DateTime.Now;
DateTime clone = foo;
```