# Datetime when assigned "dd/MM/yyyy" data but it keep store as "MM/dd/yyyy"

Tags: c#, forms, datetime, xamarin

I had an issue when assigning DateTime object lets say a :-
DateTime object1 = "03/11/2021"; // 3rd November 2021 into another DateTime object
DateTime object2 = object1;

Then object2 would become "11/03/2021" automatically.
I tried hard creating a new DateTime object and the result still similar.
Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Snipshot of the original code]
[image: Watch]

Comment: A `DateTime`, internally, is just a count of 100ns intervals since midnight at the start of 01/01/0001. Any formatting you're observing is happen when you *convert it to a string*. Internally it has no format information, and like I say, is just a count.

Comment: For your information, Datetime is a struct (value type). It clone each allocation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265399/how-can-i-clone-a-datetime-object-in-c
`user.CheckinDt = logusr.CheckinDt //clone value`

Comment: You can try : `user.CheckinDt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)`

Comment: @Tohm .. The value in my newdt is correct. It is what i stored in the sqlite. But when assign to the user.CheckinDt the ticks it is seeing a different value. I read through the pinned, but did i clone to my user.CheckinDt ?? cause i am assigning `user.CheckinDt = new DateTime(Year,Month,Day)` , can advise what to change there?

Comment: Please do not post code or errors as images.  Please post a [MCVE] that demonstrates the problem

Comment: It is obviously not re-creatable with: `var newDt = new DateTime(2021, 11, 3);
var checkinDt = new DateTime(newDt.Year, newDt.Month, newDt.Day, newDt.Hour, newDt.Minute, newDt.Second);` So perhaps there is something going on in the `checkinDt` property in the user class?

Comment: `sqlLite.SqlLiteDtFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"` ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all: `DateTime object1 = "03/11/2021";` - you don't have it - it would not compile, as `string` is not implicitly convertible to `DateTime`.

Secondly: `DateTime` is nothing more than just a numeric representation of time. So under the hood it is nothing more than just a number (as mentioned, number of ns since a given point in time). How the date is displayed is just a minor concern - value under the hood remains the same.

Please read on how to format date in C# and how to parse it.

Comment: Please see my screenshot. My question is not my actual code. It just for explaining. I am not assigning 03/11/2021 to my datetime. I am pretty sure the object i am passing in is not stored properly.